# Problem downloading file from FTP using QNetworkAccessManager::get() function

Tags: c++, qt

This is my first request.. :)

I am having some problem using the QT framework and downloading a single file (12kb long) from a FTP server. Some info regarding the problem:

- the environment is linux embedded (yocto) using QT 5.10
- the network connection of the device is ethernet, via LTE connection(quectel modem mc25)
- the ftp server is with no tlc and no ssl protection (customer's ftp server..)
- the server port is 2121
- the same code works using a normal ethernet (RJ cable) connection
- the same LTE connection via modem , works using "wget" linux tool for downloading.
- the ftp client mode is passive (I have read wget  output)
- trying on different ftp server (address and server are different) I have never experienced problem, the same code works in other ftp server (for sure with tlc and ssl protection), also using LTE modem.
- the problem is only on that ftp , also uploading the file.

What I experience is that I have no error message from `QNetworkAccessManager`, nor from `QNetworkRequest` object. Simply no anser, no error. Capturing `QmetaObjectChange` signal, I see only the code `200` from the server and the size of the file. Stop.

Any Ideas that can help me to find the reason why I experiment this strange behaviour?
Thanks for your help.

Alberto.

Comment: Please show your actual code. Maybe you are just using `QNetworkAccessManager` or `QNetworkRequest` incorrectly, but we can't see what you are doing.

Comment: Hi Remi, the code is based on this example.. https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/downloadmanager?h=5.14 ..infact works for all ftp servers and all connections , except for that one!

Comment: UPDATE: I tried the above example code from outside my company (I am at home), using an ubuntu PC and qt5.10 and I cannot download the file. The above code give me the following warnings..  qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method Very strange, cause using qt on embedded device did not give me that warning. However the result is the same: I cannot download the file!

Comment: seems the problem is on openssl that remove sslv2. I have to recompile openssl enabling that protocol.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/711863/installing-qt-5-5-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-throws-qt-network-ssl-error-on-terminal thanks to all! : )

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood the problem.
 
Openssl library has intentionally disabled the use of obsolete and dangerous protocols like sslv2.That's why QT cannot download the file from that particular ftp server: the server uses sslv2.
Using obsolete protocols like sslv2 introduce the possibility that hackers can obtain sensible data intercepting your network session.
 
I think the best solution is to avoid my software to connect to such kind of ftp servers, I do not want to allow security problem also on my system.I will prompt an error message like : "error: the ftp server use an osolete and dangerous protocol(sslv2). Connection not allowed." 
You can connect a slot to signal in order to get ssl warnings..

```
void DownloadManager::doDownload(const QUrl &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

#if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
            SLOT(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
#endif

    currentDownloads.append(reply);
}
```

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/download/main.cpp?h=5.14

BR!
: )